# z3: adding variable declarations in the assertions

Tags: z3

Is there a way to add the function definitions as assertions in the solver?

I am currently working on bounded model checking of C++ files and being able to add the definitions as assert statements will provide sort of a one to one correspondence to solver assertion and line of code.

For example I have the following toy program:

```
int x, y;
x = y + 1;
assert(x != 0)
```

CBMC produces the following smt2 file:

```
(declare-fun |main::1::y!0@1#1| () (_ BitVec 32))
(define-fun |main::1::x!0@1#2| () (_ BitVec 32) (bvadd (_ bv1 32) |main::1::y!0@1#1|))
(define-fun |B0| () Bool (= |main::1::y!0@1#1| |main::1::y!0@1#1|))
(assert (not (not (= |main::1::x!0@1#2| (_ bv0 32)))))
```

z3_parse_string returns the following formula.

```
Not(Not(1 + main::1::y!0@1#1 == 0))
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to add the function declarations into the solver as well, something along the lines of:

```
(x!0@1#2 == 1 + y!0@1#1) AND !(x!0@1#2 == 0)
```

So each clause corresponds loosely to one line of source code.

I understand that currently the z3_parse_string api only access the (assert... lines and does folding from there (please correct me if I am wrong) 
The only solution I can think of is modifying the file such that the define-fun becomes declare-fun and the definition is pushed into a new assertion line like:

```
(declare-fun |main::1::x!0@1#2| () (_ BitVec 32))
(assert (= |main::1::x!0@1#2| (bvadd (_ bv1 32) |main::1::y!0@1#1|)))
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more examples or actual code (CBMC or Z3) I don't have a better solution either. In general, I would discourage people from using `Z3_parse_string` altogether, it often creates more confusion than necessary. It's better to either switch to full SMT2-files via the command line, or go all the way and translate the problem into Z3-API calls (excluding string parsing etc). Last I checked, CBMC had an API backend for Z3, so that should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yeah, z3_parse_string is not the most user friendly, I ended up having to come up with my own parser to shift the declaration bit into a new assertion clause.
CBMC only generates the smt2 file and calls z3 natively, it then retrieves the assignment of relevant variables and uses that to generate the error trace.
Thanks a lot though